# How to change behavior of class not changing its implementation (which pattern?)

Tags: design-patterns

Today on interview I was asked a question: *how to change a given class behavior not changing its implementation?*

I reviewed behavioral patterns and didn't find the answer.

We were talking about patterns, solid and IoCs

I suppose the question connected with some mechanisms of injection functionallity to existing class.
I don't think it's connected with extention methods or just inheritance.

For example there is a class:

```
OrdersService{
     //some methods here
}
```

We need to extend its behavior with logging etc. without changing the implementation.
I.e. we shouldn't do this:

```
OrdersService{
     private ILogger _logger

     //some methods here
     OrdersService(ILogger logger)
    {
       _logger = logger;
    }     
}
```

Comment: Sure that you have not mispelled the question ? The behavior can be changed only by changing the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the interviewer wanted you to suggest creating another class that inherited from that class, and substituting your inherited class for the original class?

The [Liskov Subtitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) says:

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming. It
>   states that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then
>   objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e.,
>   objects of type S may substitute objects of type T) without altering
>   any of the desirable properties of that program (correctness, task
>   performed, etc.)

ETA:  It would seem that if the original author of the class did not intend you to be able to change the behavior, you can't do it easily.  But if it was properly created using dependency injection, you can control aspects of its behavior by changing the identities of the classes that are injected.

If the `OrdersService` class takes an injected object of some type, an `OrderRepository` for example, you can create a `LoggingOrderRepository` that performs logging in addition to the tasks of the original `OrderRepository`.  (Merging logging with data access isn't that good an implementation idea, but it's just an example.)  The `Liskov Substitution Principle` says that the `OrdersService` will be able to deal with the `LoggingOrderRepository` just as it dealt with the original `OrderRepository`.

There is also the [Stategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), as David Osborne suggested in his answer.  However, this also requires that the original author of the class have intended that you be able to pick among a family of algorithms to be executed.  But it sounds closest to the original question as you have stated it.

Answer (score 0):

By using an injected strategy you can alter a class's behaviour without changing its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It sound to me like [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Strategy_and_open.2Fclosed_principle).

> ...The strategy pattern uses composition instead of inheritance. In the strategy pattern, behaviors are defined as separate interfaces and specific classes that implement these interfaces. This allows better decoupling between the behavior and the class that uses the behavior. **The behavior can be changed without breaking the classes that use it, and the classes can switch between behaviors by changing the specific implementation used without requiring any significant code changes**.